# How to install qwtpolar library on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qwt

I'm trying to install newest version of qwtpolar on my ubuntu 12.04. Before, I've installed Qt4 dev libs, Qtcreator and Qwt-dev from ubuntu repository. Everything works great.

But now I need to use a polar plot. Unfortunately there is no deb package for this lib. So I have to compile this. After downloading sources follow the instructions: 
`qmake-qt4`, `make` i got this:

`qwt_polar_fitter.h:13:30: fatal error: qwt_curve_fitter.h: No such file or directory`

`qwt_curve_fitter.h` is located in `/usr/include/qwt` directory

How can I configure `make` or `qmake-qt4` to look for files into that directory?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered adding /usr/include/qwt as include directory to the respective project (qmake) files ?
Or, alternatively you can try to add the directory to path environment (just temporarily):

```
export OLD_PATH=$PATH
export PATH=/usr/include/qwt:$PATH
# build your project
# ...
# reset PATH
export PATH=$OLD_PATH
```

Note, that both solutions are of the sort quick and dirty, but might get you back running

Answer (score 0):

OK.

I managed to install qwtpolar and add a plugin to qtcreator. Complete steps, that worked for my Ubuntu 12.04:

1) first of all we need to have installed qt4 or higher dev libs, qtcreator, qwt dev libs.

2) download sources from svn (not archive file but svn!) and follow steps in README (qmake & make & make install)

3) to add a qwtplugin to qtdesigner you need to do the following (replace x.x.x with qwtpolar version):

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/qwtpolar-x.x.x/features/qwtpolar.prf /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/`

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/qwtpolar-x.x.x/features/qwtpolarconfig.pri /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/`

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/qwtpolar-x.x.x/lib/libqwtpolar.so       /usr/lib/`

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/qwtpolar-x.x.x/lib/libqwtpolar.so.1     /usr/lib/`

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/qwtpolar-x.x.x/lib/libqwtpolar.so.1.0   /usr/lib/`

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/qwtpolar-x.x.x/lib/libqwtpolar.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/`

`sudo cp /usr/local/qwtpolar-x.x.x/plugins/designer/libqwt_polar_designer_plugin.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/designer/`

4) run qtdesigner and voila! There is a new QwtPolarPlot tab.

5) to run a qt application with qtpolarplot you only need to add 2 lines to your *.pro file:

`INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/qwtpolar-1.0.0-svn/include`

`unix|win32: LIBS += -lqwtpolar`